# How does one interpret $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ for a function which isn't invertible?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

I was just going through the proof of derivative of inverse functions.

The statement reads:

> If $y= f(x)$ is a differentiable function of $x$ such that it's inverse $x=f^{-1}(y)$ exists, then $x$ is a differentiable function of $y$ and it's derivative is $\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}, \dfrac{dy}{dx}≠0 $

Which naturally arises few questions, what if the inverse $y=f(x)$ doesn't exist?

**My Questions :**

> 

1. Does $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ still have a meaning?
2. If so then what would it mean geometrically?
3. Would $\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$ still hold? And if it does, then why do we even need the invertible condition in the statement?

Comment: answer 1 : do not exist but if piecewise inverse function exists then it exists for those partitions

Comment: answer 2: no meaning but for piecewise inverse function it has geometrical meaning as $\frac {dx}{dy}$ within each partitions

Comment: answer 3: no $\frac {dx}{dy} = \frac {1}{\frac {dy}{dx}}$ do not holds

Comment: $dx/dy$ can be interpreted as the coefficient of $dy$ for the differential form $dx$ over the submanifold $\{(x,f(x)):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ of the Euclidean plane. More analytically, the graph of $y=f(x)$ may be invertible if we restrict its domain, and then one can still regard $dx/dy$ as the derivative of that 'local inverse'.

Comment: @WesleyStrik updated

Answer (score 0):

Notationwise, you should interpret $$\frac {dx}{dy}= \frac{ df^{-1}(y)}{dy}$$

Where we have defined $y = f(x)$ so $x = f^{-1}(y)$, now if the function $f$ is not invertible, we know that the inverse relation $f^{-1}$ is not a proper function even to begin with, so differentiation does not make an awful lot of sense.

Take the parabola $y=x^2$, it does not have one unique inverse over $\mathbb R$, it has two possible 'inverses' $\pm \sqrt x$, this has two slopes for every $x$, opposite and equal and that's why we cannot define a unique derivative. We usually interpret $\frac{dx}{dy}$ as the slope of the inverse function, but for non-invertible functions we run into problems. We simply do not understand what you mean by "the slope" - of what?

Comment: Exactly but taking your example, $y= x^2$ if you differentiate wrt $y$, you'll have $\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{1}{2x}$ and what does this mean?

Comment: Geometrically you inverted the slope, so the tangent lines of $x^2$ have slope $2x$, whilste the inverse has the reciprocal, they always multiply together to give you 1, see: https://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage6/Lesson/inverseDeriv.html

Comment: I don't really think there is more to it, unless you start looking at advanced stuff like differentiable manifolds and stuff like that. From an analysis point of view it just tells you how to calculate the derivative of the inverse in terms of the derivative of the original function - which sometimes is a useful technique. Again, the inverse has a very clear meaning geometrically, you mirror the function in the line $y=x$ - and your question is about the slope of this, which to me is just the slope of the inverse, which is a function, so you are asking about the slope of a function.

Comment: I mean what made the original function so special? if a function is invertible, they are each other's inverses and they thus form a dual pair of functions with the property that composition with each other in any order gives the identity (group theory)

Comment: If you do the substitution now in terms of $y$ we get that:
$$ x= \pm \sqrt{y} \implies \frac{dx}{dy}= \frac{1}{\pm 2\sqrt{y}}$$
which is precisely the slope of the 'inverse' functions $f(y)=\pm \sqrt{y}$

Comment: Bottom line: the inverse is just another function, which, if you want, you can find a derivative for. By the chain rule we can derive this useful property so we don't actually need to invert, but we can just derive the original function, which is sometimes easier for functions for which it is hard to find a closed formula inverse for (but which are definitely invertible).

Answer (score 0):

Your statement isn't actually true. For a counterexample, take $f(x)=x^3$. The inverse $f^{-1}(y)=y^{\frac13}$ exists, but is not differentiable at $y=0$.

Comment: he updated, so $y=0$ is not allowed because then the derivative is zero ($x=0$).